# Swift and arrays

Tags: swift

I am working on writing a Fibonacci number finder in Swift. I am having an issue with using a variable to access an array, like the following:

```
var i = 0;
var fibnumbers: Array = []
var lengthOfFibnumbers: Int = fibnumbers.count
var e: Int = lengthOfFibnumbers - 1
var addone: Int = fibnumbers[e]
```

When I try this, the playground shows me the red octagon with an exclamation point. When I click on it, it gives the following error: `Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments`.

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you declare fibnumbers?

Comment: @Cezar like so: 

`var fibnumbers: Array = []
var lengthOfFibnumbers: Int = fibnumbers.count
var e: Int = lengthOfFibnumbers - 1
var addone: Int = fibnumbers[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should declare fibnumbers as an array of Int:

```
var fibnumbers: [Int] = []
```

"Array" is defined as a generic (Array). When you don't provide a type for "Array" it is assumed to be "AnyObject". The error you are getting is a little weird but really it is because you are trying to assign the result of the subscript to an `Int` when you need to convert it from an `AnyObject` to an `Int`. For example, this compiles fine: `var addone : AnyObject = fibnumbers[e]` So it isn't really the subscript that is the problem, despite what the error says.

Comment: drewag, why is that? I should be able to access an array using a variable for the index value anyway...

Comment: @drewag Can I ask why you init the Array `var fibnumbers: Int[] = []` instead of  `var fibnumbers = Int[]()`

Comment: @markhunte Both ways produce the same result. It is really just a matter of personal preference but I feel that `[]` is more concise and more consistent with cases where you want to provide specific values `[1,2,3,4]`